# Set Theory: Proof of existence of surjection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

As part of a larger proof, I have to show that there does not exist a surjection $\pi: A \rightarrow P(A)$, where $P(A)$ is the power set of the set $A$.

I am having a problem with the proof given in the book. It is given as follows:

Assume towards a contradiction that there exists a surjection $\pi: A \rightarrow P(A)$ and define $$ B = \{x \in A | x \notin \pi (x)\}.$$
Then $x \in B$ $\iff$  $x\notin \pi(x)$.  $B$ is a subset of $A$, and since $\pi$ is a surjection, there exists $b \in A$ such that $B = \pi(b)$.

Then we have that $b \in B$ $\iff$ $b \notin \pi(b) = B$.  Contradiction.

My question is: how can it be fine to define B in the first place?  I feel like saying there exists such a set is based on the assumption that $\pi$ is not a surjection.  If there was a surjection, then B would be empty.  Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There is no problem to define a set that happens to be empty. There is never a claim that the set contains any elements.

Comment: Also, $B$ won't be empty, because any $x\in A$ that gets mapped to $\emptyset \in P(A)$ will be an element of $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points here:

1. If $B$ is empty it's fine. Because $\varnothing\in\mathcal P(A)$, so it is a valid candidate for being in the range of $\pi$.
2. There is no need to assume that $\pi$ is a surjection. Just take *any* function $\pi\colon A\to\mathcal P(A)$, and define $B$ as in the proof, then $B$ is not in the range of $\pi$ (in particular, it means $\pi$ cannot be surjective).

   What is imperative to remember here is that $B$ depends on $\pi$. So different functions define different $B$'s. But the definition is fine because $\pi$ is given, and we can always determine whether or not $a\in\pi(a)$, so we can always determine if $a\in B$ or not.

Comment: Then can't we use an identical proof to show that no surjection exists between sets X and Y when X is a subset of Y?

Comment: How would that proof go?

Comment: Assume there is a surjection f: X $\rightarrow$ Y and define B to be the set { x $\in$ X | x $\notin$ f(x)}.   Then x $\in$ B $\iff$ x $\notin$ f(x). B is a subset of X, and f is a surjection, so there exists b $\in$ X such that f(b) = B.  Then we have that b $\in$ B $\iff$ b $\notin$ B.

Comment: If $Y$ is not the power set of $X$, then $B$ is not a valid candidate for an element in the range; and similarly the statement $x\notin f(x)$ makes little sense if $f(x)$ is not a subset of $X$, not that it doesn't make sense at all, just that it has little to no use here.

Comment: What you wrote is blatantly false, sine $\mathcal P(A)$ is not a subset of $A$. But what you meant, perhaps, that $\pi(x)\subseteq A$ is in fact true.

Comment: Sorry, my computer died in the middle of writing that.  What I meant was:
Since $\pi(x) \in$ P(A) implies that $\pi$(x)$\in$ A, we can define B as all the x's $\in$ A such that x $\notin$ P(A).  In this case, can I apply this proof to show that no surjection exists between any sets X and Y whenever Y is a subset of X?

Comment: No, but $\pi(x)\in\mathcal P(A)$ means only that $\pi(x)\subseteq A$, not that $\pi(x)\in A$.

Answer (score 1):

$B$ is defined to be the set of all elements in $A$ that are not mapped to a set containing themselves by $\pi$. As $\pi$ is a surjection by assumption all this means is that any $x  \in B$ contained in any set $S$ in $P(A)$ requires that $S$ is the mapping of some $y \in \{ z \in A:z \neq x \} $ under $\pi$. I.e $S=\pi (y)$.

Comment: The word "onto" is being used in a non-standard way here.

Comment: Yes sorry that had some nonsense surjectivity connotations so I've changed it. That's just the word my mind most associates with the mapping of elements between sets.

Answer (score 0):

For each $x$ in $A$, $π(x)$ is a subset of A.  So either $x$ is in $π(x)$ or it isn't.  We are letting $B$ be the set of $x$'s for which it isn't.

We could also give a name such as $C$ to the set of $x$'s for which it is true that $x$ is in $π(x)$.  If we did, then $B$ and $C$ would partition $A$.

Since $B$ is a subset of $A$ and $π$ is surjective, then there is some element, call it $b$, that $π$ maps to $B$.  The contradiction comes from considering whether or not $b$ is an element of $B$.  That is, whether $b$ is in $B$ or $C$.  If we assume $b$ is in $B$, then we can argue that it is in $C$ and vice versa.  However, $B$ and $C$ are disjoint giving us the contradiction.